# Show Joomla component outside Joomla!

Tags: joomla-2.5

I have a website with Joomla and phpbb too. I would like to include a joomla chat extension to be vieweable into my phpbb forum too. Is this possible?

This chat extension is not handled by a module (otherwise I know it would be impossible since every module has got "defined('_JEXEC') or die ('No direct access');"

Thanks.

Comment: Components also have the defined or die statement.  You can probably wrap it in an iframe,  or you could invert the scenario and show the forum in Joomla with a custom component

Comment: I'd prefer to only add the Component outside Joomla. If this is achieveable by an iframe, could you please help me in this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, there is now way to call a component without proper Joomla CMS initilization.

However, you can call an Url to generate the component alone, adding these parameters "tmpl=component".

For example: http://www.joomla.org/index.php?tmpl=component

Furthermore, as @bakual notes:

> To be precise, &tmpl=component will load the component.php within your active template directory, with a fallback to /templates/system/component.php. Usually that one only loads the component (plus system messages) however it could do anything you want. You could also use other values like &tmpl=foo which would load /templates/yourtemplate/foo.php

Comment: Do I need to add &print=1 any time? Or can I just put ?tmpl=component?

Comment: Also, what if I do not have a index.php in the URL? And, last question, I do have to replace the "component" with the url of my component right?

Comment: I'm close to the solution. If I type: http://mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_jchat&tmpl=component&view=1 i feel like I am close to the real solution. I got a blank page with the following error: Requested controller file not found

Comment: You can just use tmpl=component I don't see any reason why you'd need print=1

Comment: Right, I think print parameter comes from J15 times

Comment: To be precise, `&tmpl=component` will load the `component.php` within your active template directory, with a fallback to `/templates/system/component.php`. Usually that one only loads the component (plus system messages) however it could do anything you want.
You could also use other values like `&tmpl=foo` which would load /templates/yourtemplate/foo.php.